# Save a array to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I got this API Moves PHP Script up and running, but i can't seem to figure out how to save the array to a MySQL db? How do i do that? I want to save the information, but also print the information on the page like i do now?

I use the script from this git .. https://github.com/borivojevic/moves-api-php

$Moves = new \Moves\Moves($access_token);

```
    $data = $Moves->dailySummary(array('pastDays' => 1));


    foreach($data as $dag)
    {
        echo 'Dato: <b>', $dag['date'], '</b> <br />';

        foreach($dag['summary'] as $aktivitet)
        {
            if($aktivitet['activity'] == 'walking')
            {
                $daglig_procent = ($aktivitet['steps']/10000 * 100);
                echo 'Antal skridt: <i>', $aktivitet['steps'], '</i>';
                echo '<br />';
                echo 'Procent: <i>', round($daglig_procent),  ' &#37; </i>'; 

            }
        }
                    echo '<hr />';

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save an array to a db, json_encode it and save the json string in a text/varchar field; json_decode it to get the array back from the db data.

Comment: I don't understand? Something similar to this? https://github.com/adamwulf/json-to-mysql/blob/master/example.php

Comment: Mike, that solution creates a new table for the data: totally different from your original question. If that is what you want then why not use that github project?

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm not very good at this.. I want to save the data to the user profile..?

Answer (score 0):

This this an example:
    `$mydata=Array("some"=>Array("fhdlslfd"=>"gklhml", "giuolmmlh"), "gfukilfkgl");`

You can simply use `serialize($mydata);`  for add in bdd and `unserialize($resultatsql);` for use the vars from bdd

Answer (score 0):

You can use these function

[serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)
or 
[json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)